# Automagically detecting timezone from reliable system sources

Tags: php, linux, date, timezone

I'm writing a CLI PHP script, and I want the log messages it'll display to contain the correct local time.

This script will be being included in a small software release and run on different machines (on Linux) as part of a configuration step. I only need the time to correctly timestamp log messages, none of the other parts of the system need current-time information, and my use of PHP is an implementation detail, so I feel it would be unreasonable to require users (who may be installing PHP just to run this) to edit the script or fiddle with their PHP installation to set `date.timezone`.

I say the above in light of the fact that...

- `python -c 'import datetime; print datetime.datetime.now()'`
- `ruby -e 'print Time.now, "\n"'`
- `perl -MPOSIX -le 'print strftime "%F %T", localtime $^T'`
- `awk 'BEGIN { print strftime("%F %T", systime()) }'`
- `date`

...are all properly cognizant of the fact that it's not *quite* 4AM, but has in fact just gone half past three in the afternoon instead.

Initially Node.js seemed to be in the same stubborn-UTC camp, but it seems there are libraries that are able to autodetect the current timezone and apply it. I'm not aware of anything similar for PHP.

And unfortunately, according to https://bojanz.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/detecting-the-system-timezone-php/, PHP stopped looking at the system's idea of the timezone in version 5.4, back in 2012.

I don't fully understand why PHP decided to just throw in the towel and resort to "user-hardcoded or bust" when 4 other major programming languages I just tested worked fine.

That being said, I trust there's a valid reason, and I would very much like to read about it.

On my (Slackware) system TZ is unset, but `/etc/localtime` is a copy of my timezone file. Note that it's **not** a symlink, so the `readlink()` workaround noted in the above link is irrelevant for me.

I've repeatedly wondered how complex it would be to actually open and parse my localtime file.

The DateTime and various date functions provide no way to parse arbitrary tzinfo files.

`strace`ing PHP shows that it opens and reads `/etc/localtime` as it starts up, but depressingly the language doesn't expose the loaded data in any way.

I wasn't able to find any duplicates of this question, but I'll be *very* surprised if there are none since this has been an arguably open issue for just under 6 years at time of writing this.

Comment: Just to be clear, is your question just how to read the system local time zone identifier from within PHP?  (I didn't see an actual question in the above.)

Comment: That would work, yes. You're right, the actual question is a bit obtuse - I'm looking for pretty much any solution that allows PHP to know the correct current time relative to my PC's clock as opposed to UTC. I presume this will mean doing timezone offsetting and that's fine (hopefully a good solution isn't overly hacky).

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would want to set the timezone in php.ini depending on your application requirements, but I understand that for a CLI tool that you are going to use manually as opposed to a cron job you may want to use the system timezone. You could try this:

```
$ret = null;
$output = null;

exec('date +%Z', $output, $ret);

if ($ret)
{
    throw new Exception("Failed to get system timezone");
}

$timezone = $output[0];
```

You could then set that as the default timezone in your script:

```
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
```